# Trying to setup Rhode Code on Ubuntu and ran into

Tags: python, python-babel, rhodecode

While following instructions on how to setup Rhode Code listed here:

http://pythonhosted.org/RhodeCode/setup.html

I was on the step where I am supposed to use the command:

```
paster setup-rhodecode production.ini
```

I ran into the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: babel
```

I have babel installed on my system but for some reason the paster will not recognize it.

Any thoughts?

**System info:**

Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

EC2 Micro instance

Comment: Use rhodecode enterprise installer. This will fetch all the dependencies for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a broken on incomplete isntallation. I recommend using RhodeCode installer that downloads all required dependencies and takes away the hassle of installing it with all required dependencies.